# Lambda NodeJS MySQL Task Timed out

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am trying to learn how to connect MySQL using lambda functions in AWS. I have followed a couple of instructions online and basically ended up with this code:

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var pool  = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 1000,
        connectTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
        acquireTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
        timeout         : 60 * 60 * 1000,
        host: "foo-bar-123.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
        user: "root",
        password: "pass123",
        database: "sample_db",
    });

    exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {
      // prevent timeout from waiting event loop
      context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

      pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Use the connection
        connection.query('SELECT id FROM customer limit 10;', function (error, results, fields) {
          // And done with the connection.
          connection.release();
          // Handle error after the release.
          if (error) callback(error);
          else callback(null,results);
        });
      });
    };
```

This is working on my local but when I zip this code and uploaded it as a lambda function, this returns

`Response:
    {
      "errorMessage": "2018-11-13T02:16:10.339Z 0562b432-e6ea-11e8-81ef-bd64aa1af0a4 Task timed out after 30.03 seconds"
    }`

It times out no matter how many seconds I set it to.

I have pretty much set everything at default since I am new to all of these but I have added AmazonRDSFullAccess to the role of lambda function.

Does anyone have any idea what may be wrong or missing in my setup?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have Lamda running behind a VPC ?

Comment: just change the behavior such that the execution ends as soon as the callback function is called by setting callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false on the context object. bcz Default is true... you'd want to set

Comment: At first it was set to No VPC and then tried adding subnets and security group I see in my RDS instance but connection still times out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some trial and errors, I was able to make it work and what I was missing is that I did not allow `All TCP` in the inbound of my RDS Security group. After that, I set it as my lambda function to `No VPC`, and it was able to query properly.

This link: https://dzone.com/articles/querying-rds-mysql-db-with-nodejs-lambda-function and the stack overflow link posted in there (which is this: [AWS Lambda RDS connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605093/aws-lambda-rds-connection-timeout)) helped me a lot in figuring out what was wrong with my code/setup.

Here is the final code that I ended up using.

```
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const pool  = mysql.createPool({
        host: "foo-bar-123.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
        user: "root",
        password: "pass123",
        database: "sample_db"
    });

    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
      //prevent timeout from waiting event loop
      context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

      pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if(err) throw err;

        // Use the connection
        connection.query('SELECT id FROM customer limit 10;', (error, results, fields) => {

          // And done with the connection.
          connection.release();

          // Handle error after the release.
          if (error) callback(error);
          else callback(null,results);
        });
      });
    };
```

Thanks!